# Change order in #_EVENTDATES

Tags: php, date, format

I'd like to show an event is happening over multiple days in a calendar. When I use #_EVENTDATES it puts the day first, then month. This may be "correct" but my clients want to see it in standard format month/day/year.  Is there a way to change this?  thanks

Comment: We're going to need to know *a lot* more then this. What software are you using?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-events-manager-change-date-format-of-_eventdates

Answer (score 0):

I kind of found an answer to my own question.  In the WordPress Events plugin you can override it in settings.  Still would be useful to know the answer (if there is a way) when I'm not using a plugin with this feature though.